# Tweepy reply to latest tweet goes in a loop

Tags: python, api, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I have the following code, where I start a stream to a user, and when he makes a new tweet, I want to make 3 replies to that tweet, in order. However, the bot works ok, it finds the latest tweet, and it starts replying like crazy, randomly, without stopping. What am I doing wrong ?

```
class MyStreamListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        ### here i get the statusid from json
        ### I have 3 replies in messages.txt which i want to reply 1 by 1 to the latest tweet (statusid)
        file = open("messages.txt", "r")
        content = file.readlines()
        for line in content:
            api.update_status(line, statusid)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = MyStreamListener()
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener)
    twitterStream.filter(follow=['xxxx'])
```

Thank you !

Comment: check statusid with print(statusid) because from your code, it comes from nowhere. Neither : api.

Answer (score 1):

Tip : you must mention the user at the beginning of your answer to reply correctly. Here is the full code :

```
import tweepy

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        file = open("messages.txt", "r")
        content = file.readlines()
        for line in content:
            print("answering @" + status.user.screen_name + " tweetID " + status.id_str + " with : " + line.rstrip())
            api.update_status(status="@" + status.user.screen_name + " " + line, in_reply_to_status_id=status.id)            

consumer_key = '***'
consumer_secret = '***'
access_token = '***'
access_token_secret = '***'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth, MyStreamListener())
myStream.filter(follow=['xxx'])
```

Comment: The code works, but it still goes in a loop and posts until you stop the bot.

Comment: The problem is that the bot replies to its own replies as well, that's how it goes in the loop

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the loop is that the 'follow' stream returns all replies to the followed user (as well as retweets of, and by, the user), so you need to exclude these before continuing to the reply lines. See the [Twitter Documentation.](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters)

For example, if using `on_data()` rather than `on_status()`, check this `from_creator()` before proceeding with the rest of the `on_status()` function (note that `on_status()` returns deletions etc., which will throw an error in this function so handle appropriately):

```
def from_creator(status):
    status = json.loads(status)
    if "retweeted_status" in status:
        return False
    elif status["in_reply_to_status_id"] != None:
        return False
    elif status["in_reply_to_screen_name"] != None:
        return False
    elif status["in_reply_to_user_id"] != None:
        return False
    else:
        # status is an origin Tweet by the followed user!
        return True
```

If using `on_status()`, it would be:

```
def from_creator(status):
    if hasattr(status, 'retweeted_status'):
        return False
    elif status.in_reply_to_status_id != None:
        return False
    elif status.in_reply_to_screen_name != None:
        return False
    elif status.in_reply_to_user_id != None:
        return False
    else:
        # status is an origin Tweet by the followed user!
        return True
```